# migrate mvc razor project to react project

Tags: reactjs, .net-core, migration

I'm trying to make sense on how to migrate a legacy .net core mvc razor page project to a single page application using react in several iterations.

This blog post helped me on the way, and it makes sense: [Frankenstein code migration](https://medium.com/@tysonnero/iteratively-migrating-asp-net-mvc-razor-to-react-typescript-e0330fe81b4e)
I've tried some of this approach, but I'm finding myself stuck on introducing the isolated application in the project.

From the moment a basic react app is introduced i receive tons of typscript errors originating form the root node_modules folder on building the project concerning missing declarations/extensions/generics (e.g. ts2314 and ts2315 errors).

I suppose it has to do with conflicting tsconfig.json files since the project I'm trying to migrate already has some react/js/ts embedded on razor pages inside it.

this is the tsconfig from the existing project:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": [
      "ESNext",
      "dom",
      "es2015",
      "es5",
      "es6",
      "ES2016",
      "ES2017"
    ]
  },
  "include": [ "wwwroot/src/js" ]
}
```

and this is the tsconfig in the /App folder containing my isolated app

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "testUtils": ["src/utils/testUtils"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*", "jest.setup"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}
```

I suppose that packages could call the wrong node_modules folder, but I have no clue on how to configure this...

Any advice on how to tackle my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I feel stupid for having to post this, but make sure the visual studio 2022 typescript compiler is **turned off** when working with libraries like gulp/grunt/webpack as that is their job. Then make sure your entry points and output for js/ts/css files do not conflict with eachother and you are good to go.